# Granting a local user rights to a share

Tags: windows

I was wondering if someone could help.

I have two Windows Server2008R2 servers. Both servers are members of the domain. 
On server1 I have created a local user (TestUser). Server2 has few LUNs presented to it. On one of the drives(G:), I have created a share called MISC. I want to give permission to TestUser (a local user on server1) to have full access to share \servername\MISC on server2.
Is that possible?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly assign Share or NTFS permissions on the shared folder on Server2 for a local user from Server1. You can though, do the following to make this work.

1. Create a matching user on Server2 for the user you created on Server1. Set the password for both users to be the same. Set the appropriate share and NTFS permissions on the shared folder for the user you created on Server2. When the user on Server1 accesses the share on Server2, Windows will use passthrough authentication to grant the user from Server1 access to the shared folder.